# Binary multiplication

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Please don't be to harsh with me if you think that this is to simple, I just don't understand it.

I been trying to follow this [site](http://ecen3233.okstate.edu/PDF/Labs/Combinational%20Multiplier.pdf)(Method 2) to solve simple multiplication of $3 * 3 = 9$, but it doesn't work for me.

Please tell me what am I missing.

[Full screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVzKI.png)

[image]

Comment: Something's wrong with that sketch...I think it'll be easier to understand that from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Binary_multi1.jpg

Comment: It seems to me that in the first entry of the first row, the y input should be T, not F.

Comment: @TonyK Can you be more specific?

Comment: Well, what do _you_ think that input should be?

Comment: Not that it affects the result here. But in general it will.

Comment: @TonyK I understand you now. But as you said it doesn't effect the resoult

Comment: @TonyK he is trying to implement a Carry Save Array Multiplier circuit, like this one: http://www.ellab.physics.upatras.gr/~bakalis/Eudoxus/CSAM.html

Comment: @Realz: Yes, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing carry propagation after the last row. The last box in the last row has a Carry output equal to T, which has to be incorporated into the result.

Comment: Will this avoid the extra propagation? http://dc93.4shared.com/doc/SNHFbgBx/preview.html, section 2.5.1 Array Multiplier, http://i.imgur.com/IajqRRU.png, http://i.imgur.com/jeFSFnB.png

Comment: Carry = sum and p or carry and (sum xor p); p = x * y; the carry in the last row is false for all the boxes.

Comment: I don't know what "sum and p or carry and (sum xor p)" means to you, because you haven't bracketed your terms. But in my book, that final box should be outputting a non-zero carry. (And it does give the correct answer.)

Comment: I found the solution by adding the carry to the left instead to the bottom left.

Comment: Well that's as clear as mud...